# ERROR: ec2_vpc_subnet is not a legal parameter of an Ansible Play

Tags: yaml, ansible

I am trying the below code in Ansible to create a subnet with an existing VPC.

```
---
  - hosts: local
    connection: local
    tasks:
      - name: Create subnet
        ec2_vpc_subnet:
          state: present
          vpc_id: vpc-abcd
          cidr: 10.0.3.0/24
          resource_tags:
            Name: Database Subnet
        register: database_subnet
```

I am getting this error when I run this playbook

```
ERROR: ec2_vpc_subnet is not a legal parameter of an Ansible Play
```

This is exactly as per Ansible documention here: 
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_vpc_subnet_module.html#requirements-on-host-that-executes-module

Kindly help me resolve this issue.

Comment: which version of Ansible are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ec2_vpc_subnet` is support from Ansible version 2.0 and if you are on < 2.0 version, this won't work for you.

See the `new in version` tag at the top of http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_vpc_subnet_module.html#requirements-on-host-that-executes-module